Trigger Jenkins parametrized build execution on remote server via curl request and pass credentials to it
I have 2 Jenkins instances. After a build on Jenkins1 has finished I want it to trigger another build on Jenkins2. My build invokes an ansible playbook which performs SVN update and is parametrized - users have to write their SVN credentials and SVN revision in order to execute the build. The same build must be triggered on Jenkins2.
My parameters are as follows:
String Parameter - USER
Password Parameter - PASS
String Parameter - REVISION

I have configured the following post build script on Jenkins1, which successfully triggers the build on Jenkins2:
curl POST http://JENKINS2:8080/job/test/buildWithParameters \
  --user user:token \
  --data "REVISION=$REVISION" \
  --data "USER=$USER" \
  --data "PASS=$PASS"

The issue is that the parameters are not passed correctly from Jenkins1 to Jenkins2. Here is the log from the failed build on Jenkins2:
/usr/bin/ansible-playbook test.yml -f 5 --private-key /tmp/ssh.key -u jenkins \
  -e user={AQAAABAAAAAQdPfG8ioIGy+FX2QsIG/P/SS5O5YIEmnUK/8l/jKF8Ac=} \
  -e ******** \
  -e revision={AQAAABAAAAAQPhzpgyl6n5lTlOcOFzy8yr8F8AvvoPNM0BKklbYa81w=}

It seems to me that the parameters are encoded. I also tried using --data-url-encode but to no avail.
I must specify that it is not possible to use stored credentials via the credentials plugin, because we use AD authentication, different users will be starting the build and passwords in the organization must be changed every 40 days. It would be way easier to just pass the credentials every single time.
EDIT:
Turns out the problem was not in the curl request at all.
I have configured extra variables (key/value):
keys: user, pass, revision
values: $USER, $PASS, $REVISION
and it now works.
My mistake was that I had initially left the value fields empty and jenkins automatically assigned random string values.

Your command should fail with curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST. This kind of destroys faith that the rest of the command is pasted correctly.

You are right.
I changed the request to:
curl -X POST http://JENKINS2:8080/job/test/buildWithParameters --user user:token --data "REVISION=$REVISION" --data "USER=$USER" --data "PASS=$PASS"
Now I no longer get the "Could not resolve host" error but the parameters still aren't being passed correctly.

Since you are doing everything right in principal, it must be some kind of implementation misstep. Let's start with prepending your curl command with echo and checking that parameter expansion gives you the values you expect.

It seems that the issue is not caused by curl at all. Upon starting the build on Jenkins2 (not triggering it remotely) the parameters are still encoded in the output log.

Then add your Jenkins2 pipeline code to the question.

You should go with the following curl command:
curl -X POST http://JENKINS2:8080/job/test/buildWithParameters \
  --user user:token \
  --form "REVISION=$REVISION" \
  --form "USER=$USER" \
  --form "PASS=$PASS"

From the documentation:

This lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. This causes curl to POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data according to RFC 2388.

